# What are the origins of the IE css hacks?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I was tweaking a website to make it work with IE7, and was wondering: where do all these IE hacks come from?

The thing is I can't imagine a guy saying "Yeah, we're not gonna implement `display: inline-block`, but `*display: inline` will work".

That doesn't make sense to me. So who created these hacks? Did someone invented them as a substitute for some properties that don't work or is this pure luck that this works?

PS: I understand if you want to close this question as off-topic or something else, but if at least you have a link or something about that I would appreciate :)

Comment: I think they pull them out of a rabbit's arse. Or is it a hat, I forget....

Comment: http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200512/the_history_of_css_hacks/

I think I recall seeing a few css hacks named after people a few years ago, when I had to support IE6. I think they were kind of just discovered/blogged about by a wide array of developers...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that the hacks work is variations and mistakes in the implementation of the browsers, mostly in older version of Internet Explorer.

Many hacks revolve around unusual reactions to unusual combinations of selectors. Often used is combinations of selectors that are illegal according to the standards. As the standards doesn't specify how illegal code should work, different browsers react differently to it, and this is used to target specific browsers.

In the example `*display: inline;`, there is a combination of a buggy implementation and a variation in error handling. In IE the `inline` mode is implemented somewhat like `inline-block` in other browsers, and using the asterisk in the selector makes other browsers ignore the rule. The hack will apply `display: inline;` in older versions of IE and leave other browsers to use the `display: inline-block;` rule.